# Javascript: trouble with conditional comparison – monkey business

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

Sometimes this code works properly but it depends on where I place the part that I want executed, which is really saying that it doesn’t work at all – but I really have no idea why not. Perhaps one of you all might be able to offer some insight:

```
function displayBanner(currentDate) {
    var munf = currentDate.getMonth();

    var imageSrc = "defaultLogo.gif";   

    imageSrc = (munf == 9) ? ("fallLogo.gif") : ("defaultLogo.gif");
    imageSrc = (munf == 8) ? ("fallLogo.gif") : ("defaultLogo.gif");
    imageSrc = (munf == 10) ? ("fallLogo.gif") : ("defaultLogo.gif");

    imageSrc = (munf == 11) ? ("winterLogo.gif") : ("defaultLogo.gif");
    imageSrc = (munf == 0) ? ("winterLogo.gif") : ("defaultLogo.gif");
    imageSrc = (munf == 1) ? ("winterLogo.gif") : ("defaultLogo.gif");

    imageSrc = (munf == 2) ? ("springLogo.gif") : ("defaultLogo.gif");
    imageSrc = (munf == 3) ? ("springLogo.gif") : ("defaultLogo.gif");
    imageSrc = (munf == 4) ? ("springLogo.gif") : ("defaultLogo.gif");

    imageSrc = (munf == 7) ? ("summerLogo.gif") : ("defaultLogo.gif");
    imageSrc = (munf == 5) ? ("summerLogo.gif") : ("defaultLogo.gif");
    imageSrc = (munf == 6) ? ("summerLogo.gif") : ("defaultLogo.gif");

    return imageSrc;
}
```

Comment: How are you calling the function? SHow a snippet of the code where you do it.

Answer (score 1):

You have a logic problem.
What is happening is that all comparisons are occurring even if the right month is found.
you should try a switch...case approach:

```
switch(numf) {
    case 9:
    case 8:
    case 10:
        imageSrc = 'fallLogo.gif';
        break;
    case 11:
    case 0:
    case 1:
        imageSrc = 'winterLogo.gif';
        break;
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
        imageSrc = 'springLogo.gif';
        break;
    case 7:
    case 5:
    case 6:
        imageSrc = 'summerLogo.gif';
        break;
    default:
        imageSrc = 'defaultLogo.gif';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only the last assignation will ever influence the final value of imageSrc, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
function displayBanner(currentDate) {

    var munf = currentDate.getMonth();

    var imageSrc = "defaultLogo.gif";

    if ( munf > 7 && munf < 11 ) {
         imageSrc = 'fallLogo.gif';
    } else if ( munf > 10 || munf < 2 ) {
         imageSrc = 'winterLogo.gif';
    } else if ( munf > 1 && munf < 5 ) {
         imageSrc = 'springLogo.gif';
    } else if ( munf > 4 && munf < 8 ) {
        imageSrc = 'summerLogo.gif';
    }

    return imageSrc;
}
```

Comment: a gentleman and a scholar, please accept my most sincere thanks.

Answer (score 0):

imageSrc will be defaultLogo.gif in all months except July (last line).

You are much better off using a switch statement:

```
switch(munf) {
    case 9:
    case 8:
    case 10:
        return "fallLogo.gif";
    case 11:
    case 0:
    case 1:
        return "winterLogo.gif";
    ...
    default:
        return "defaultLogo.gif";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every assignment happens, and so every decision made is overruled by the following one.

Let's say for example that `munf` is 9. The line

```
imageSrc = (munf == 9) ? ("fallLogo.gif") : ("defaultLogo.gif");
```

sets `imageSrc` to `"fallLogo.gif"` as expected. But then

```
imageSrc = (munf == 8) ? ("fallLogo.gif") : ("defaultLogo.gif");
```

also runs, and because `munf` is not 8, it sets `imageSrc` again, to `"defaultLogo.gif"`. This happens on each of the following assignments too, so only the last one has any noticeable effect.

What you need to do then is to avoid changing `imageSrc` back to the default. The closest to your original code is this:

```
function displayBanner(currentDate) {
    var munf = currentDate.getMonth();

    var imageSrc = "defaultLogo.gif";   

    if (munf == 9) {
        imageSrc = "fallLogo.gif";
    }
    if (munf == 8) {
        imageSrc = "fallLogo.gif";
    }
    ...
    return imageSrc;
}
```

The other answers show more concise ways of doing this, from using `else if`, through handling three months with each condition, to using `switch` which is made for this sort of thing. Thanks everyone!

One other thing: you can run lots of tests on your function at once, like this:

```
function runTests() {
    var date;

    date = new Date(2013, 0, 1);
    console.assert(displayBanner(date) == 'winterLogo.gif');

    date = new Date(2013, 1, 1);
    console.assert(displayBanner(date) == 'winterLogo.gif');

    date = new Date(2013, 2, 1);
    console.assert(displayBanner(date) == 'springLogo.gif');
    ...
}
```

This is called unit testing, and it's very useful for chasing bugs out of your code and keeping them out.